# CLLocationManagerDelegate with wrong timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have implemented a tracking app that works 24h in the background. Sometimes I notice that the timestamp and the location do not match. E.g. if I'm travelling by car or train I have recorded locations with a distance of 50km and an accuracy < 2km while the timestamps have a difference of 6 minutes.

So how can I make sure that the data is correct?

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {}
```

Currently I sort the locations by accuracy and only take the best one for the records. Is it better to take only the last one? Or all?

Here is how I setup the locationmanager:

```
private func setupLocationManager() {

           self.locationManager.delegate = self
           self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
           self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
           self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 300
           self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
           self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
           self.locationManager.activityType = .other
    }
```

I'm doing this in a separate class an not in my AppDelegate. This class lives in an instance variable in my appdelegate.

Comment: Show us how you are setting up your locationManager and its settings. AFAIK last is always the best. Additionally I think this is all because your `desiredAccuracy` is set to something very inaccurate. This could also be because the time settings are mismatched ie your phone is 6 minutes ahead of your server or whatever

Comment: Thanks! I added my setup code.

Comment: Did you verify if you don't have a timing mismatch?

Comment: What do you mean with this? I now changed my verification code to print out a warning if a travel of more then 10km has been done with more then 300km/h and let it run with my records for my tests. This happens regularly. It would be ok if the accuracy would be bad, but it isn't.

Comment: I mean maybe the time of your phone is 10:00 while the time of your sever is 10:06 or whatever else that your are measuring it against...

Comment: There is no server involved - everything happens on the phone and stays there. I found this on my own test runs.